# Finding names with a specific letter on parser server

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am currently working on Android platform using parse server. I am making a function in which if i enter a character key it shows all the entries which are having that letter in it. 
For example - i will be getting all the names starting or having character "p" in them.

I would really appreciate if u can suggest, find or give me some examples of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the documentation as your first resource. Parse is pretty well documented, and the ParseQuery class has a function specifically for this.

http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-Android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html#whereContains(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)